# UItextField Delegate not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

In my iPad app I have two textfields. One displays the normal, default textfield and the other should display a picker as its input view.

Problem is, once I use the `txt1` which displays default keyboard and then when I touch the 2nd textField the `txt1` keyboard is staying visible.

I have also written `[txt1 resignFirstResponder];` `[txt2 resignFirstResponder];` while displaying the picker.

I have checked the txt1 `IBOutlet` connection and the delegate assignment, those seem to be correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: You may not have specified the input view property properly of txt2., that's why its showing keyboard of txt2

Comment: where have you written '[txt1 resignFirstResponder]; & [txt2 resignFirstResponder];'?

Comment: Don't write [txt2 resignFirstResponder]; for txt2, just change its inputview property

Comment: @Hadely - How to set inputView property.

Comment: @lukya - txtDidBeginEditing after checking respective textField & also in displayPicker method

Comment: @J61: Write resignFirstResponder in txtDidEndEditing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the following code :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if(textField == txt1)
   {
       return YES;
   }
   else
   {
       return NO; // Write the code for displaying UIPickerView instead of the Keyboard.
   }
}
```

Hope this might solve your issue......

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement below method to resign Keyboard......

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: yes, i have implemented this method but it still not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
 txt2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == txt1)
    {
        [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
        // code for Hide Picker 
        return YES;
    }
    else {
       // [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
        [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
        // code for go in picker 
        return YES;
    }
}
```

[for more information](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/23911-uitextfield-disable-keyboard.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have u implemented this method ??

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad` method write this,

```
txt2.inputView = pickerView;
```

and other `resignFirstResponder` codes should be placed correctly , by this on Tapping txt2, you will directly get pickerview instead of Keyboard.

Comment: pickerview should be inside a UIView.

Comment: and add that UIView instead of picker directly

Comment: then txt2.inputView = objView;

Answer (score 0):

did you implement the delegates property of `UITextFieldDelegates` to in the header file, if not do that and check